# Cannot assign text value 'CharacterEllipsis' into property 'TextTrimming' of type 'TextTrimming' error

Tags: wpf, windows-store-apps, textblock

I got a compile error on Windows Store app (Windows 8.0)

Cannot assign text value 'CharacterEllipsis' into property 'TextTrimming' of type 'TextTrimming'

I set it WordEllipsis it works for the TextBlock.

Any idea?

Comment: It may be helpful to show us the code you're using to set the `TextTrimming` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CharacterEllipsis` is not supported for Windows 8.0. It got introduced in Windows 8.1

MSDN link - [**TextTrimming**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.texttrimming.aspx)
[image]

Comment: Interesting =O The MSDN page for the WPF TextBlock http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming%28v=vs.110%29.aspx doesn't list that restriction, and I've used it in my desktop apps. I'm guessing this is actually a WinRT / Windows store thing, and not WPF?

Comment: @Chris - Yeah right it's WinRT. OP mentioned in question that its Window Store App.

Comment: I figured, so the question is mistagged as WPF. Glad for the clarification.